# How can I connect Windows XP 32 bit to a Windows 7 comp (64 bit) using cross-over RJ45 cable

Tags: networking

I have one computer running on Windows 7 and I want to connect this to another comp running on Windows xp. Both computers have ethernet cards from different manufacturers and they have been connected using a cross over RJ45 cable.

I have tried to ping the two computers but I am receiving two kinds of error messages

1. Request timed out (error on the xp comp)
2. Destination host unreachable (on the Windows 7 comp).

Can someone tell me what network setting I should perform from the beginning to establish a connection between the two comp.

Comment: What address did you put in (and in what application) to get the request time out or destinatoin unreachable messages? Windows supports RFC3927, which uses self-assigned addresses to enable two computers to communicate without DHCP or configuration. You should however address the other computer by their computer name.

Comment: Not all NICs support crossover cables. otoh, a lot of modern NICs support auto MDI-X, meaning they don't need crossover cables for this - a standard patch cable will do. Have you tried that? Beyond that...  Do the two NICs show link LEDs on? Does the network configuration applet in Windows show "connected" on each machine?

Answer (score 1):

Configure a static IP on each network card.  So you could use 192.168.1.5 for one and 192.168.1.6 for the other with a subnet of 255.255.255.0  No default gateway or DNS are needed as you are simply connecting the two systems. You would need to connect to the opposite PC by IP address as you will not have any name resolution system.

This should allow a connection quickly.

Make usre you have a quality CAT5e cross over cable.